# Proper way to add credential to a URL string?

Tags: c#

Simple problem. I have a URL, and I need to add the username and password to enter credentials.

I wanted to know if there is a method in C# which would receive the URL string and the credentials and return the URL with credentials in it. I'd like to do exactly what I do with this function, but this function is reading specific strings and may eventually cause errors:
(it just add the username and the credentials)

```
url = url.Substring(0, url.IndexOf("/") + 2) + userName + ":" + password + "@" + url.Substring(url.IndexOf("/") + 2);
```

This way of doing is really static... I need to obtain the final string of the URL.

Comment: Are you changing URL parameters or complete URL?    "which would receive the URL string and the credentials and return the URL with credentials in it." Bit confusing

Comment: Adding "username" and "password" at URL is not a good way to do it. Every server want it difference. Read this first : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789031(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Generally not a good idea to include credentials the way you have illustrated in the URL.You could pass the credentials encrypted as a HTTP header, which is a name/value pair, and you wouldn't need to do the kind of parsing you are doing

Comment: thanks all for the quick response!! Pippi Longstocking answer solved my solution perfectly!!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `UriBuilder`:

```
var uri = new Uri("http://www.example.org");
var uriWithCred = new UriBuilder(uri) { UserName = "u", Password = "p" }.Uri;
```

which generates:

```
http://u:p@www.example.org/
```

Comment: If the username or the password contains a ':' or a '@', this produces an error. Is there anyway to improve this?

Answer (score 2):

Credits to the answer above, to handle the @, #, :, etc characters you'll need to URL encode the user and the password:

```
  public static string CreateProtectedURL(string url, string username, string password)
    {
       
        var uri_protected= (new UriBuilder( new Uri(url)) { UserName = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(username), Password = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(password) }.Uri);

        return uri_protected.AbsoluteUri.ToString(); //will work in browser

       // return HttpUtility.UrlDecode(uri_protected.AbsoluteUri); //will not work in browser, you will get the normal url with user and pass 
    }
```